# Angular cache not working on phonegap app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, caching, ionic-framework

I'm using ionic and angular for building a mobile app. But I'm getting the following errors every time I integrate angular-cache in the app:

[image]

Here's what my `index.html` file looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-cache/dist/angular-cache.min.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <script src="js/controllers/home-starter.js"></script>

    <script src="js/controllers/home/loginController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/home/signupController.js"></script>


    <script src="js/services/services-starter.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services/userService.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter" animation="slide-left-right-ios7">

    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then on my `app.js` file I set angular data as one my dependencies:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'angular-data.DSCacheFactory'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, DSCacheFactory) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

    DSCacheFactory('UserCache', {
      storageMode: 'localStorage',
      deleteOnExpire: 'aggressive'
    });


  });

})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {


  // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
  // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
  // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
  // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
  $stateProvider


    .state('login', {
      url: '/login',
      templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
      controller: 'LoginController'
     })


    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

});
```

I've put the logic for logging in in my `userService.js` file:

```
(function(){

    angular.module('starter.services')
    .service('UserService', ['$http', '$q', '$ionicLoading', 'DSCacheFactory', UserService]);

    function UserService($http, $q, $ionicLoading, DSCacheFactory){

        var base_url = 'http://somewhere.com';

        self.UserCache = DSCacheFactory.get('UserCache');

        self.UserCache.setOptions({
            onExpire: function(key, value){
                login.then(function(){
                }, function(){
                    self.UserCache.put(key, value);
                });
            }
        });


        function login(user){

            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var cache_key = 'user';

            $ionicLoading.show();

            $http.post(base_url + '/api/login', user)
                .success(function(data){

                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                    self.UserCache.put(cache_key, data.user);
                    deferred.resolve(data);

                })
                .error(function(data){
                    deferred.reject();  
                });


            return deferred.promise;
        };

         return({
            login: login
        });

    };


})();
```

And if it helps, here's my `config.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.vestor507394" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>tester</name>
  <description>
        An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.
    </description>
  <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">
      Ionic Framework Team
    </author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true"/>
  </feature>
</widget>
```

It seems to work fine when I just run it from the browser. But as soon as I upload to phonegap build and install the app on Genymotion, I get those errors. If I don't use angular cache on code, it also works fine.

Any ideas what could I be doing wrong? Do I need to install any plugins or edit the `config.xml` file to make this work? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please remove your service declaration out of the (function(){ declaration :

```
angular.module('starter.services')
.service('UserService', ['$http', '$q', '$ionicLoading', 'DSCacheFactory', UserService]);

function UserService($http, $q, $ionicLoading, DSCacheFactory){ .................
```

Hope this helps !!.